# get latest data from table

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using jdbc to insert and getvalues form my database.
Suppose my sql table is like this-

```
NAME | STATE
  x      in
  y      in
  z      in
  x      out
  y      out
  z      out
  x      in
  y      in
```

As you can see there are similar values in the above table. I know how to normally get the value from table but i want to get the most recent added value of lets say 'z' which was added to the table or the last entry of z from the above table how can i get it? 
Another column of type timestamp is there but when you are getting the value you only have name 'z' you don't know when the last entry was in the table

Comment: use order by DESC in your query

Comment: How to determine what was inserted last?

Comment: how you define  the last entry.. have a datetime ,, an id? ..

Comment: There is no concept of 'latest', except what you define (eg through an update timestamp or something similar).

Comment: a column date of type timestamp is there in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what does LIMIT 1 do?

Comment: Only give last one record

Comment: As you can see from above table if i want to get value of 'z' then this will give me last entered value right

Comment: Yes. Give last inserted record